# React Native: Find position of color in linear gradient

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have a color picker where I can drag a cursor across a linear gradient and it selects the color the cursor is on.

I want to update the color picker so that given a `startingColor`, it determines the location of the cursor for that color.

#### Components

I have a linear gradient

```
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";

<LinearGradient
  colors={["#BF81CF", "#E075AB", "#EB5E5E", "#E37861", "#F5E769", "#81CF84", "#A5AEFF", "#B0AFAF"]}
  ...
/>
```

Every time I drag the cursor I determine the corresponding color by doing the following (*I'm using react-native-reanimated*):

```
  const translateX = useSharedValue(0);

  const animatedColorPreviewStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const inputRange = colors.map(
      (_, index) => (index / colors.length) * maxWidth + CIRCLE_COLOR_VIEWER
    );

    const backgroundColor = interpolateColor(
      translateX.value,
      inputRange,
      colors,
      "RGB"
    );

    onColorChanged?.(backgroundColor);

    return {
      backgroundColor,
    };
  });
```

Given `startingColor = "#e76b5f"`, how do I determine what the `translateX.value` needs to be?

### Attempts

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (startingColor) {
      const startingColorInt = parseInt(startingColor.substring(1), 16);
      const inputRange = colors
        .map((item) => parseInt(item.substring(1), 16))
        .sort()
        .reverse();
      const outputRange = colors.map(
        (_, index) => (index / colors.length) * maxWidth + CIRCLE_COLOR_VIEWER
      );

      const indexPosition = interpolate(
        startingColorInt,
        inputRange,
        outputRange
      );

      translateX.value = indexPosition;
    }
  }, [selectedColor]);
```

While this gives me a value in the correct range, it's incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!